# unresolved symbol for opencv error

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, dll, visual-studio-2015

I've spent the last two days trying to get opencv to work. Im using visual studio 2015 community and opencv 3.1.0. I've added all the lib files and dlls and configured the properties for the project. Any insight would be great as i really have no clue as how to fix this.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    namedWindow("win");
    waitKey(0);
    return 1;
}
```

The code above throws the following error.

`LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::namedWindow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function main   OpenCV`

Comment: you need to link opencv_highgui310(d).lib, or opencv_world310(d).lib

Answer (score 0):

`namedWindow` belongs to `highgui` library. Try adding

```
#include<opencv2\highgui.hpp>
```

and also link the corresponding library.

Also, `namedWindow` has two arguments: `"windowName"` and `CV_WINDOW_TYPE`, where the latter can be:

```
CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE
CV_WINDOW_NORMAL
```

and some other options

Comment: Ive linked the library, i still get the same error. Ive also added the second argument to the function and its to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Comment: `unresolve external symbol` is very likely due to the fact that you didn't link the *library*. In your code, you did link the header file, but the library is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the bin folder path as an environment variable. For example, add "D:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin" to PATH. Then close and re-open Visual Studio.